# Mesos: batch scheduler framework that supports concurrent job execution?

Tags: apache, scheduled-tasks, mesos

I would like to use Apache Mesos for doing batch scheduling. I am now looking for a good batch scheduling [framework](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/frameworks/).
I looked in detail at [Apache Chronos](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/) and [Apache Aurora](http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/features/cron-jobs/#collision-policies), but none of the two support concurrent execution (of the same job *), which is a feature I really need.
Is there an alternative framework that would fit my requirement?

Thank you

(*) suppose a given job takes on average 1.5 minutes but I schedule it every 1 minute: I need concurrent overlapping executions of the same job. On Chronos 1 out of 2 execution will be skipped. On Aurora, there is an option to either kill the existing running execution, or cancel the new execution (but no option to have the 2 executions running in parallel).

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "concurrent job execution"? Chronos supports the execution of multiple jobs at once...

Comment: @Tobi suppose a given job takes on average 1.5 minutes but I schedule it every 1 minute: I need concurrent executions of the same job. On Chronos 1 out of 2 execution will be skipped.

Comment: Would it really make sense to run a job every minute which needs 1,5 minutes to complete? Over time, this would mean that the "job stack" would rise and rise...

Comment: @Tobi the job stack would rise only if new executions cannot start until all previous ones are completed. I need the new job to start, on scheduled time, even if the previous execution is not finished. That way there is no stack. Just 2 concurrent executions.

Comment: But that's not what you described earlier IMHO... You were saying you want overlapping executions, and in your last comment you say the contrary

Comment: Have you looked at [GoDocker](https://bitbucket.org/osallou/go-docker) or [JobServer](http://www.grandlogic.com/content/html_docs/jobserver.html)

Comment: @MichaelClosson Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: @Tobi , I read again my last comment. I don't see any contradiction. I am sorry of you don't get my point.